# Find difference between rows by id, but place difference on first row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have read a few different posts about finding the difference between two different rows in R using `dplyr`. However, the posts I have seen do not give me quite what I want. I would like to find the difference between the times, and place that difference between n and n+1 in a new variable, on the same row as n, kind of like the duration between n and n+1. All other posts place the elapsed time on the same row as n+1.

Here is some sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
id time
1   1
1   4
1   7
2   5
2   10"), header = T)
```

My desired output:

```
# id  time duration
#  1     1        3
#  1     4        3
#  1     7       NA
#  2     5        5
#  2    10       NA
```

I have the following code at the moment:

```
df %>% arrange(id, time) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(duration = time - lag(time))
```

Please let me know how I should change this around. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff()`, appending the NA to each group.  Just change your `mutate()` call to

```
mutate(duration = c(diff(time), NA)))
```

**Edit:**  To clarify, the code above is only the `mutate()` call at the end of the pipe in the code shown in the question.  So the the entire operation would be, based on the code shown in the question, is

```
df %>% 
    arrange(id, time) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(duration = c(diff(time), NA)) 
# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# Groups: id [2]
#
#      id  time duration
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1     1        3
# 2     1     4        3
# 3     1     7       NA
# 4     2     5        5
# 5     2    10       NA
```

Comment: So this `diff` is different than the base version?

Comment: @RonakShah this is the base version

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer  When I do `diff(df$time)` I get different results with negative values. This one treats negative as `NA`

Comment: @RonakShah - I don't follow.  This appends NA to the end of the `diff` result, like the OP asks for.  I don't get any negative results.  Are you sure you're doing the grouping?

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer your answer is correct. However, can you try `diff(df$time)` ? It gives me output as `[1]  3  3 -2  5` .

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer okay. I get it now. It is because of grouping the result here is `3  3 NA 5` and not `3 3 -2 5`. Thanks :-)

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer The solution you proposed has worked great for me, but now that I reran my code (i haven't changed anything), I am getting negative results instead of NA. Any idea what cause the change?

Comment: @RichScriven sorry tagged the wrong person. Please see my comment/question above.

Answer (score 0):

We can swap `lag` with `lead`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(duration = lead(time)- time)
#      id  time duration
#    <int> <int>    <int> 
#1     1     1        3
#2     1     4        3
#3     1     7       NA
#4     2     5        5
#5     2    10       NA
```

---

A corresponding option in `data.table` would be `shift` with `type = "lead"`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, duration := shift(time, type = "lead") - time, by = id]
```

NOTE: In the example the 'id', 'time' were in order.  If it is not, add the `order` statement as the OP showed in his post.